# Rails5: How to format currency values from API data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Ruby on Rails application that successfully requested data from an API but want it to be in the standard format of 4,992.02 instead of 4,992.0293

```
<div class="card-body">
  <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title"><i class="fa fa-gbp" aria-hidden="true"></i><%= @bitcoin ["bpi"]["GBP"]["rate"] %></h1>
</div>
```

so the [Rate] is where the number is coming from. Used the standard number_to_currency method

```
<%= @bitcoin ["bpi"]["GBP"] number_to_currency(["rate"]) %>
```

but get error

updated with error 
  <%= @bitcoin ["bpi"]["GBP"] number_to_currency(["rate"]) %>

```
/Users/neilpatel/Desktop/2018/rails/bit/app/views/home/index.html.erb:13: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' ...bpi"]["GBP"] number_to_currency(["rate"]) );@output_buffer.s... ... ^
```

Comment: can you show us error?

Comment: did  <%= @bitcoin ["bpi"]["GBP"]["rate"].to_d %> this is gives me 5.0

Comment: @Neil its already comes as a string, also you cant parse it to decimal because it contains `comma` and `dot`. You have to create custom helper for it. Like in my answer.

Comment: thats because of converting to decimal and rounding if you remove .to_d you will get the whole number

Answer (score 0):

Use cant use `round`, sting contains `,` comma.

```
// helpers/app_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
   def coin_to_currency(number)
           n = number.split(".")
           num = n[0]
           dec = n[1].slice(0..1)
           number_to_currency([num, dec].join("."))
   end
end


// view
<%= coin_to_currency( PLACE_COIN_NUMBER_HERE ) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I suggest you this solution for your request:

This lines in your controller:

```
@split_result = '4,992.0293'.split(',')
@result = @split_result[0] + @split_result[1].to_f.round(2).to_s
```

This line goes to your view:

```
<%=  number_with_delimiter(@result) %>
```

This is result from your input **'4,992.0293'** and it is **rounded up** to 2 decimal places because 0293 if you cut to 2 numbers then corrected value is 03.

[image]

Comment: The number comes from coindesk API so it will change, every minute. I have been using ['rate'] which gives me 4,992.0293 but I have ["rate_floats"] that does not have commas. It now gives m 5001.131 so really just need to remove the last digit

Comment: hmm if so unstandard I think you should do some validation of number before like check if he has decimal, or if he has comma or.. chars like that.. and make rest of logic...  Also I suggesting you that check gems like rails-money and ruby money it can be very very useful in this situations.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"4,9920.0293"[/[\d+,?\d+]+\.?\d{0,2}/]
 => "4,9920.02"
```

Comment: To help readers understand your solution, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted question